# Cocos2d Timer to delete objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to create a timer in Cocos2d in which an object is created and deleted 5 seconds after it is created. Does anyone know how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you are trying to delete a CCSprite when you said object.  You setup a timer to call a method which then deletes the sprite by the tag number that you assigned it when you created the sprite (lets pretend you assigned the tag number 10 for the example below)

```
[self schedule: @selector(delete) interval:5];

-(void)delete{
       [self removeChildByTag:10 cleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: I prefer ur answer than NSTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You can use NSTimer like this :

```
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeSprite) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)removeSprite {

 [self removeChild:spriteName cleanUp:YES];

}
```